# JSON Dictionary to CoreData

Tags: ios, json, core-data, swift3

Ok so I'm able to parse my JSON to my Model struct which looks like this:
JSON:

```
{  
   "base":"CHF",
   "date":"2017-02-09",
   "rates":{  
      "AUD":1.3086,
      "BGN":1.8326,
      "BRL":3.123,
      "CAD":1.3133,
      "CNY":6.879,
      "CZK":25.32,
      "DKK":6.9665,
      "GBP":0.79732,
      "HKD":7.7729,
      "HRK":6.9992,
      "HUF":289.31,
      "IDR":13280.0,
      "ILS":3.7553,
      "INR":66.867,
      "JPY":112.48,
      "KRW":1146.2,
      "MXN":20.482,
      "MYR":4.4473,
      "NOK":8.3265,
      "NZD":1.3871,
      "PHP":50.008,
      "PLN":4.0382,
      "RON":4.2115,
      "RUB":58.914,
      "SEK":8.8863,
      "SGD":1.4173,
      "THB":35.076,
      "TRY":3.7,
      "USD":1.0019,
      "ZAR":13.435,
      "EUR":0.93703
   }
}
```

MODEL:

```
struct TestStruct {

    var base: String
    var date: String
    var rates: [String: Double]

    init(base: String, date: String, rates: [String:Double]) {
        self.base = base
        self.date = date
        self.rates = rates
    }
}
```

But now I have no Idea how I'm going to store my Model in CoreData I know how store the base and date because those are just strings but how can I store a Dictionary or maybe convert it to something because I will need the "rates" Dictionary back from CoreData since I need to know which currency has which exchange rate...

Comment: You need to read the Core Data documentation and then follow a tutorial. Core Data is a great technology but you need to understand the concepts underlying it. There are various tutorials on the internet or on iTunesU (I recommend `Developing iOS 9 Apps With Swift`).

Comment: @RoboticCat Thx, I'll make sure to check them out.

Comment: https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord is a easy way to use coredata

Answer (score 0):

Core Data is so complex that I suggest you search on Google for tutorials. However, I built the proper data model. May it help you.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! It certainly makes it a bit easier to understand...So with your data model would I just create another struct for my Rates dictionary, split the dictionary into String and Double and "attribute" would be where I save the string and "attribute1" the double?

Comment: @L.B. No, Core Data has its own class (subclass of NSManagedObject).

Comment: Well RIP me indeed then...thats gonna be a nightmare to figure out